# How do I enable authenticated users to be able to add ubercart products?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I’m new to drupal, so I apologize if my questions are too basic

Any help would be appreciated

I’m using drupal 7 with Ubercart version 7.x-3.8

With Ubercart Auction module version 7.x-1.x-dev

I’m trying to create a car auctioning website, where users can place a car up for auction and other users can bid on it.

How do I enable authenticated users to be able to add ubercart products?

Comment: I've made this one question (which seems a pretty reasonable one to me), if you need to know about deleting products please ask a separate question. You'll need to provide more information about what you mean than _How do I Delete unwanted Ubercart products?_, for example in what context do you want them deleted, what does "unwanted" actually mean, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to narrow down the question and be more specific. Please excuse me , I'm still new to this. I will try to improve my question

Comment: I have used the feeds import to import some products.. Unfortunetly the products that were imported were all incorrect. So now I have a list of UberCart products which are incorrect.. >>> I would like to delete these product using the "admin" user

Answer (score 0):

Ubercart products are nodes, so access is controlled in the normal way:

Visit the permissions page, and assign whatever roles make sense to the "create", "edit", etc permissions for the relevant product content type.